# System.ValueType[*,*,*] to byte[*,*,*]

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Изначально это был тип `array<System::ValueType^, 3>`, в массиве содержатся данные картинки(грабятся с камеры), этот плагин написан на с++. при передаче данного массива в другой плагин(написан на С#) тип меняется на `System.ValueType[*,*,*]` но для дальнейшей обработки данных принимается только тип `byte[*,*,*]`.
Как перевести `System.ValueType[*,*,*] to byte[*,*,*]` в C#?

пробовал перевести так: `if ((Value != null) && (Value is byte[,,])) { BitmapRAW = (byte[,,])Value; NewImageEvent.Set(); }
            else if ((Value != null) && (Value is System.ValueType[,,])) { BitmapRAW = (System.ValueType[,,])Value; NewImageEvent.Set(); }
            else
            {
                cPluginEntry.Message("No Type", new Exception(((object)Value).GetType().ToString()), null);
            }` но не выходит ругается на запись `BitmapRAW = (System.ValueType[,,])Value;`

Value это массив с данными капртинки из другого плагина;
BitmapRAW это байтовый массив для дальнейшей работы с картинкой;

Comment: Вариант 2. Лучше... на с++  вернуть в том типе, который нужен. Вариант 3 Или вернуть указатель, а в "import" части верно задать тип. Вариант 4. Может вам лучше создать HBITMAP/HDC - его хорошо подхватит GDI+ у с#

Comment: Вариант1 влоб, InterpropServices копать. Создать GCHandle на базе первого, перевести её в указатель  `GCHandle.ToIntPtr( h=GCHandle.Alloc(Value ))` а дальше...   Marshal мучать, что б указатель перевести куда нужно. В крайнем случе ReadByte - уже сможете по байту вычитать. Ещё может ReadIntPtr понадобится, не помню какая там модель памяти (напрямую переменная такого типа хранится или через указатель).

Comment: Мне кажется... GDI+ будет само проще вам. Там ф-ция получения RAW из битмаба есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я думаю GDI+ не подойдет, потому что мне далее надо будет вывести эту картинку в web интерфейсе через определныый порт

Comment: Ну... тогда... как самый простейший метод - работайте с указателями.